# Enemy shooting bullets every 5 seconds in unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, I am trying to make the enemy shoot at the player every 5 seconds and right now it is just shooting lots of bullets constantly in a line.
This is my code, I would really appreciate some help!

```
  void ShootAtPlayer()
{
    StartCoroutine(bulletshooting());
    IEnumerator bulletshooting()
    {

        shooting = true;

        if (shooting == true)
        {


            GameObject tempBullet = Instantiate(enemyBullet, eyes.gameObject.transform.position, eyes.gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject; //shoots from enemies eyes
            Rigidbody tempRigidBodyBullet = tempBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            tempRigidBodyBullet.AddForce(tempRigidBodyBullet.transform.forward * enemyBulletSpeed);
            Destroy(tempBullet, 0.1f);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f);

        }


        shooting = false;


    }
```

Comment: How does this even work, nothing sets shooting to true?

Comment: my bad i just changed it to what it was before, shooting = true was meant to be at the top

Comment: I posted an answer fixing what i think is a few issues in the code

Comment: How is `ShootAtPlayer` called? And you should move the `bulletShooting` to the outer scope

Comment: shootAtPlayer is called in the update when the enemy is close enough to the player, shootAtPlayer is called and it should shoot @derHugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment

> shootAtPlayer is called in the update when the enemy is close enough to the player

The issue is: You are starting a new Coroutine **every frame**!

In your case I wouldn't use a Coroutine at all since you already have a code that is executed every frame. (Because otherwise you would need some code to also **stop** the running routine)

Rather use a simple timer:

```
[SerializeField] private float cooldown = 5;
private float cooldownTimer;

void ShootAtPlayer()
{
    cooldownTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(cooldownTimer > 0) return;

    cooldownTimer = cooldown;
     
    GameObject tempBullet = Instantiate(enemyBullet, eyes.gameObject.transform.position, eyes.gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject; //shoots from enemies eyes
    Rigidbody tempRigidBodyBullet = tempBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    tempRigidBodyBullet.AddForce(tempRigidBodyBullet.transform.forward * enemyBulletSpeed);
    Destroy(tempBullet, 0.1f);
}
```

---

If you really want to use a Coroutine for that it would probably look like

```
private bool isShooting;

void ShootAtPlayer()
{
    // Only allow a new routine if there is none running already
    if(isShooting) return;

    StartCoroutine (shootRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator shootRoutine()
{
    // Just in case avoid concurrent routines
    if(isShooting) yield break;

    isShooting = true;
     
    GameObject tempBullet = Instantiate(enemyBullet, eyes.gameObject.transform.position, eyes.gameObject.transform.rotation) as GameObject; //shoots from enemies eyes
    Rigidbody tempRigidBodyBullet = tempBullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    tempRigidBodyBullet.AddForce(tempRigidBodyBullet.transform.forward * enemyBulletSpeed);
    Destroy(tempBullet, 0.1f);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (5f);

    isShooting = false;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank your very much for your help, i didn't think to do it this way!

Comment: why is the return needed here ' if(cooldownTimer > 0) return;' @derHugo

Comment: Because you don't want to shoot until the cooldownTimer is exceeded